# MongoDB auto increment ID

Tags: mongodb

The size of the auto generated ID in MongodDB is `12 Bytes` and the size of a big integer is `8 bytes`. I have a mongodb cluster on 4 machines running Ubuntu Server, but I am just testing things now. Inserts can be done only through one server which is a nodejs server, but updates and deletes can be done using various machines running a native c application all around the world and the nodejs server.

Since I have full control over inserts, wouldn't it be better to use an auto increment id?

- in 1MB of memory you can save 87381 of 12 byte ids and 131027 of the 8
  byte ids.
- is it worth it to go for auto increment ids and is there a benefit
  other than saving memory?
- performance-wise wouldn't comparing a 8 byte id be faster than a 12
  byte id, and wouldn't it reduce the size if i do indexing?

How am i doing it :

i have this document

```
{id:0 latestId:174845423}
```

i very rarely increment it by 1, most of my inserts are bulk inserts, so the nodejs server modifies the documents to be inserted in a loop giving each one an incremented id, at the end of the insert operation i add i update the lastest id with the last id value.

Comment: How often would you generate a new ID? Realize there is no such thing as an "auto incremented field" type in MongoDB, so you would need to use patterns like: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/

Comment: @WiredPrairie 98% of my daily operations are reads and updates, as i said inserts happen only on a single nodejs server so i could make a document that have the id field, and add to it when the insert operations are done, they are usually bulk inserts, so i can add the id to the documents to be inserted and at the end of the insert, increment the id document by the number of documents inserted, so the insert operations are orchestrated and i have full control over them

Comment: If you can guarantee that the Ids will be unique, and that the node process will never repeat an Id, you could use it. However, if the node process dies suddenly ... how will you restart the ID generation unless you've saved the last value somewhere outside of the node process?

Comment: @WiredPrairie i update the question with my current method, thanks for pointing to the nodejs server dies part, but other than that do i get any benifits?

Comment: Perhaps not worth the trouble of complexity it brings

Comment: This feels like premature optimization. The memory difference isn't significant, the comparison time difference is not measurable (8-12 bytes?), and sure the indexes would be slightly smaller ... but whether it's worth it really is up to you. If you're happy with your solution and understand the potential issues, I wouldn't suggest you switch to something else.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"Auto-increment" is always a problem when working with a distributed system, as it creates a bottle-neck: Each new increment needs to read the previous data .. like some other parallel requests.

Generally speaking, "auto-increment" restricts parallelism, specially on distributed systems.

Comment: i will be doing the increments on the nodejs server before i insert the documents the nodejs server does have track of the latest id so i won't rely on the database to get the latest id value, so this way i will avoid having to read the previous data, in this case wouldn't this config be better that the auto generated id?

Comment: It sounds like you are only moving the bottleneck from the DB to the nodejs server. Maybe, you should ask yourself the question if this bottleneck will restrict you or not. If it is not, then don't think too much and continue your program in anyway you can.

Answer (score 6):

There is another approach we use, when the business usecase requires to have incremented number value for a document.

In the database we create a collection with the indexes:

```
db.createCollection('sequences');
```

Later, we need the incremented value for a collection, we create a sequence:

```
db.sequences.insertOne ( {_id: 'orderId' , value : 0 } );
```

Then, when we need the next value, we retrieve it with:

```
async function getNextValue(seqName) {
    const sequence = await db.sequences.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: seqName },
        { $inc: { value: 1 } },
        { returnDocument: 'after' }
    );
    return sequence.value.value;
}
```

So when creating a document, 1) we retreive the next sequence from DB, 2) add to the model, and 3) insert the document model as usual.

Benefits:

- Thread/Process/Server safe: once retrieved next value, it will be unique for a document.
- Sequance is saved inside the same database, as the collection: any code or script from any platform can insert documents.

Caveats:

- Performance. Depending on what you are doing, but usually one extra roundtrip to a database, to get the sequance, won't hurt as much.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't have a distributed system then you can use the file system (fs) module of node js and keep track of all the records there. Then you can save that value in mongo dB.

P.S. - This can work if you don't have a distributed system.

**Alternatively** 
You can make a queue of records for the incoming data entries and then save it in dB.