# MongoDB synchronous error when inserting

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm making a prototype for real-time browser game, and I insert game details with auto increment ID to database (with `mongoose`) :

I set a setGameID function to make it unique, there is no problem.

```
exports.setGameId = function(callback) {
    gameidcounter.findOneAndUpdate({},{$inc : {'counter' : 1}}).exec(function (e,c) {
           if(e) return;
            //console.log(c)
            callback(c.counter)
     })
};
```

But when I run +10 tabs with 100 MS setInterval, some rows are replacing their positions :

```
DocID  | gameID | gameData
790    | 790    | ....
791    | 791    | ....
792    | 793    | <---
793    | 792    | <---
```

I'm checking with this method if rows are incorrect:

```
game.find().exec(function (err, _game) {
    for (var i = 0; i < _game.length; i++) {
        if(_game[i].gameID+1 != _game[++i].gameID ) {
            console.log("replaced lines :", _game[i].bet_id, _game[++i]._id);
        }
    };
})
```

How can fix this issue without using any library?

---

I **solved** this problem with this method :

```
game.findOne().sort({'_id' : -1}).limit(1).exec(function (err, last_game) {
        if(last_game.gameID + 1 == _game.gameID){    
            //ok                
        }
        else {
            //error in rows
            console.log("skipped")
            gameidcounter.findOneAndUpdate({},{$inc : {'counter' : -1}}).exec(function (e,c) {})
        }
    })
```

Comment: I don't understand why you need to create your own ID when Mongo will build a default `_id` field on every insert that is unique on its own.

Comment: It's the important part of this (gambling) game. I need to show these unique gameID's to users.

Comment: ["Auto-increment" is always a problem when working with a distributed system, as it creates a bottle-neck: Each new increment needs to read the previous data .. like some other parallel requests. Generally speaking, "auto-increment" restricts parallelism, specially on distributed systems.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21218651/mongodb-auto-increment-id/21218932#21218932)